# Find square root of non-rational fraction

Tags: number-theory, contest-math

If we have to compute this without using calculator, is there a quick way to find the answer approximately of the following problem:

which one is smaller ?
$$
A = \frac{\sqrt{2007}-\sqrt{2006}}{\sqrt{2008}-\sqrt{2007}}
$$
or 
$$
B = \frac{\sqrt{2010}-\sqrt{2009}}{\sqrt{2011}-\sqrt{2010}}
$$

My thinking is to multiply A with $\displaystyle \frac{\sqrt{2008}+\sqrt{2007}}{\sqrt{2008}+\sqrt{2007}}$ and B with $\displaystyle \frac{\sqrt{2011}+\sqrt{2010}}{\sqrt{2011}+\sqrt{2010}}$, and simplify from fraction into multiplication and subtraction only to become:$A' = (\sqrt{2007}-\sqrt{2006})(\sqrt{2008}+\sqrt{2007})$, and $B' = (\sqrt{2010}-\sqrt{2009})({\sqrt{2011}+\sqrt{2010}})$.

This form is still not easy to calculate for me.

Comment: you can use \sqrt{...} to get the root over the entire ... expression

Comment: So the idea in your last paragraph, how well does it work? Do you run into trouble?

Comment: Sorry, now i completed my last paragraph.

Comment: @kusg1: But what happens when you do those multiplications? Does it solve the problem? Do you get stuck? If so, where?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a job for calculus. Basically the question is whether the function
$$ x \mapsto \frac{\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{x-1}}{\sqrt{x+1}-{\sqrt{x}}} $$
is increasing or decreasing around $x=2010$. Since the increases of $1$ are small compared to 2010 (which in this case means that none of the relevant derivatives show much *relative* change when $x$ varies by $1$) we can probably get away with setting $g(x)=\sqrt x$ and approximating
$$ \frac{g(x)-g(x-1)}{g(x+1)-g(x)} \approx \frac{g'(x-1)}{g'(x)} \approx
\frac{g'(x)-g''(x)}{g'(x)} = 1 - \frac{g''(x)}{g'(x)} = 1 + \frac{1}{2x}$$

Comment: This looks what I look for. Thanks

Comment: From calculator, A will give 1.00024915 and B will give 1.00024871, this agrees with 1/(2*2007) > 1/(2*2010)

Answer (score 0):

Hint : the square root function is concave.

Comment: Could you give further pointer with concave definition in this context ? thanks

Comment: So ? $x \mapsto 1-e^{-x}$ is also concave, but if you go and replace the square roots with it, you get $A=B=e$